# How to Parse Json data in flutter accurately?

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, dart

I have the below Json Data(I have included only the relevant code)

The point is I am able to parse the data.But to the required string when I use substring it throws an error.

Also when I want to parse another data,I am getting as null I dont know what mistake I am doing??

Below is the code I am using to parse the Json data:

```
getDataAndPutData(String objKey, String requiredKey,
      List<String> arrayInaction) async {
    String url =
        "https://livetvapi.apyhi.com/api/v2/home?pageLocation=home&countries=IN&app_version=13&"
        "user_id=44edc2c905ae163f&package_id=livetv.movies.freemovies.watchtv.tvshows&os_platform=android";

    var res = await http
        .get(url, headers: {'Authorization': dartJsonWebTokenGenerator()});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      map = json.decode(res.body);
      data = map[objKey];
      // print(data);
      _assign(requiredKey, arrayInaction);
      setState(() {
        flag1 = true;
      });
    } else {
      CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  }


  _assign(String requiredKey, List<String> arrayInaction) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // youtubeHomeBannerMovieId.add(data.elementAt(i)["movie_id"]);s
      setState(() {
        arrayInaction.add(data[i][requiredKey].toString());
      });

    }

  }
```

The Json data is below:

```
{
"movies": [
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_cTQ3Ko9ZKg8",
      "title": "Our planet| frozen worlds",
      "tags": [
        "Documentary"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdf923885a2149948fd"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjM3NTg0NjI5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzM3NjM3NzM@._V1_SY150_CR83,0,101,150_.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cTQ3Ko9ZKg8/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-26T15:00:26.542530"
    },
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_dz3uCM-MrGY",
      "title": "Gangs Of Wasseypur 1",
      "tags": [
        "Action",
        "Crime",
        "Drama",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdc923885a2149948f7",
        "5e10bfdf923885a2149948ff"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTc5NjY4MjUwNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODM3NzM5MzE@._V1_SY150_CR0,0,101,150_.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dz3uCM-MrGY/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-26T15:00:26.613551"
    },
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_LnNcjFpILQA",
      "title": "Andhadhun",
      "tags": [
        "Crime",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfe2923885a21499490b"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZWZhMjhhZmYtOTIzOC00MGYzLWI1OGYtM2ZkN2IxNTI4ZWI3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDAzNDk0MTQ@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LnNcjFpILQA/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-26T15:00:25.941538"
    },
```

For the above data when I try to parse the data for thumbnail I call the function getDataAndPutData("movies","thumbnail",storage_array) in the initstate() of the widget

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                              width: MediaQuery
                                  .of(context)
                                  .size
                                  .width * 0.285,
                              image: storage_array[index].substring(1,storage_array.length-1),

                              placeholder: cupertinoActivityIndicator,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
```

The relevant code is storage_array[index].substring(1,storage_array.length-1),....here I am not able to find the substring.It is showing an error

Also when it comes to the below Json part:

```
"music_playlists": {
    "_id": null,
    "country": "IN",
    "category_id": "roots",
    "category_name": "Folk & Acoustic",
    "category_icons": [
      {
        "height": null,
        "url": "https://t.scdn.co/images/7fe0f2c9c91f45a3b6bae49d298201a4.jpeg",
        "width": null
      }
    ],
    "playlists": [
      {
        "playlist_name": "Afternoon Acoustic",
        "playlist_description": "Unwind and let the afternoon unfold in all its acoustic glory.",
        "playlist_url": "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX4E3UdUs7fUx",
        "playlist_total_tracks": 100,
        "playlist_images": [
          {
            "height": null,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f000000021cb21db1932b5c9139bbf136",
            "width": null
          }
        ],
        "playlist_followers": 2422456,
        "playlist_id": "37i9dQZF1DX4E3UdUs7fUx"
      },
      {
        "playlist_name": "Acoustic Covers",
        "playlist_description": "A fun mix of folksy and acoustic covers.",
        "playlist_url": "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DWXmlLSKkfdAk",
        "playlist_total_tracks": 100,
        "playlist_images": [
          {
            "height": null,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f000000022228866ad0a35846d649ef69",
            "width": null
          }
        ],
        "playlist_followers": 3635732,
        "playlist_id": "37i9dQZF1DWXmlLSKkfdAk"
      },
      {
        "playlist_name": "Your Favorite Coffeehouse",
        "playlist_description": "Curl up in your favorite spot with some sweet, mellow tunes...",
        "playlist_url": "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX6ziVCJnEm59",
        "playlist_total_tracks": 99,
        "playlist_images": [
          {
            "height": null,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f000000025ae7aa0454c9eafdd6505fda",
            "width": null
          }
        ],
        "playlist_followers": 3781866,
        "playlist_id": "37i9dQZF1DX6ziVCJnEm59"
      },
      {
        "playlist_name": "Run Wild",
        "playlist_description": "Uplifting and uptempo indie folk and roots rock, guaranteed to open your stride.",
        "playlist_url": "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX35oM5SPECmN",
        "playlist_total_tracks": 75,
        "playlist_images": [
          {
            "height": null,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000002c36f26730b007e2d54e0b337",
            "width": null
          }
        ],
        "playlist_followers": 2456280,
        "playlist_id": "37i9dQZF1DX35oM5SPECmN"
      },
      {
        "playlist_name": "Relax & Unwind",
        "playlist_description": "Let your worries and cares slip away ...",
        "playlist_url": "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DWU0ScTcjJBdj",
        "playlist_total_tracks": 100,
        "playlist_images": [
          {
            "height": null,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000002a692c498201090e78f8c9f7e",
            "width": null
          }
        ],
        "playlist_followers": 3714952,
        "playlist_id": "37i9dQZF1DWU0ScTcjJBdj"
      },
      {
        "playlist_name": "Infinite Acoustic",
        "playlist_description": "Hours of your favorite acoustic and roots music gems.",
        "playlist_url": "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX6z20IXmBjWI",
        "playlist_total_tracks": 100,
        "playlist_images": [
          {
            "height": null,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f0000000285046291c3f69d6e47fc77e1",
            "width": null
          }
        ],
        "playlist_followers": 2121952,
        "playlist_id": "37i9dQZF1DX6z20IXmBjWI"
      }
    ]
  },
  "publishers": [
```

I am getting null when I try to access the value getdata("music_playlists","category_name",storage array)

The storage array turn out to be NULL

I modified getdata function such that it returns only a string,but there also it is NULL.

I explored about creating PODO file and all that,but that I couldn't really figure out what was happening.

How to fix this problem???

Comment: Where do you create the array arrayinaction?

Comment: I have declared that in the beginning of the code.....

Comment: Add the error snippet. Either you are accessing null object or the size is bigger than the constraint

Comment: Did you initialise it? You don't show that code.

Comment: @Richard Heap yea ,I didnt show that in the code.thought it would be obvious.My bad